# JavaFX table column different font with css

Tags: css, javafx

I want to set a different font ( well actually just italics ) in one column of a JavaFX table.
I've seen this answered by calling setCellFactory and then setting the font on that.  In my view ( which with JavaFX has been regularly wrong ;-)  ) this is quite an involved and messy way to do the job - if you want to deal with editing on the cell etc. you end up with a large class instead of just using something like

```
col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<TableRow>forTableColumn());
```

So, my question is this - has anyone managed to set an id or style class on the column and reference that in css?

My attempt was something like this ( trying both class and id ):

```
col.getStyleClass().add(colDef.isItalic()? "italic-cell" : null);
col.setId(colDef.isItalic()? "italic-cell" : null);
```

and then using some combination of

```
#italic-cell
.italic-cell
#special-table .italic-cell
```

etc. etc. with

```
-fx-font-style: italic;
```

as the style for the ID / class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**CSS Styling of Table Columns**

Add an appropriate style class to your column:

```
nameColumn.getStyleClass().add("italic");
```

Add a stylesheet to your scene which defines the italic style for table cells:

```
.italic.table-cell { -fx-font-style: italic; }
```

*Caveat 1*

I tried this example again based on T-and-M Mike's comments and indeed it didn't quite work right on OS X 10.9 with Java 8.  I believe, on windows just setting the `-fx-font-style` to italic allowed the text to show in italic.  On a Mac, this will set the font to System Italic, which is a font which does not seem to exist, so the text just displays without italics.  If you also set the font family to some font for which italics are defined, then the text in the column will show in italic as expected.  For example, use Times New Roman, italic:

```
.italic.table-cell { 
  -fx-font-family: "Times New Roman"; 
  -fx-font-style: italic; 
}
```

*Caveat 2*

On Java 8b132 on OS X 10.9, there is a slight rendering bug when the table is first displayed where the table content is slightly out of line with the table headers.

Calling `table.requestLayout();` after the table was shown on the screen seemed to fix the alignment rendering bug for the table, but if everything was working right, the call wouldn't be necessary.

**Executable Sample**

Test output result on Win7 + Java 8b91:

[image: payees]

*CellShadedTable.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// demonstrates styling column cells in a tableview.
public class CellShadedTable extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("So called friends . . .");

    // create a table.
    TableColumn<Friend, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Friend, String>("name"));
    nameColumn.setPrefWidth(75);
    nameColumn.getStyleClass().add("italic");

    TableColumn<Friend, String> owesMeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Owes Me");
    owesMeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Friend, String>("owesMe"));
    owesMeColumn.setPrefWidth(150);

    TableColumn<Friend, Boolean> willPayColumn = new TableColumn<>("Will Pay Up");
    willPayColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Friend, Boolean>("willPay"));
    willPayColumn.setPrefWidth(75);

    TableView<Friend> table = new TableView(Friend.data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(
      nameColumn,
      owesMeColumn,
      willPayColumn
    );
    table.setPrefHeight(200);
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
    stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("cell-shader.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.show();

    table.requestLayout();
  }
}
```

*Friend.java*

```
import javafx.collections.*;

/** Sample data for a table view */
public class Friend {
  final static public ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new Friend("George", "Movie Ticket", true),
    new Friend("Irene", "Pay Raise", false),
    new Friend("Ralph", "Return my Douglas Adams Books", false),
    new Friend("Otto", "Game of Golf", true),
    new Friend("Sally", "$12,045.98", false),
    new Friend("Antoine", "Latte", true)
  );

  final private String  name;
  final private String  owesMe;
  final private boolean willPay;
  public Friend(String name, String owesMe, boolean willPay) {
    this.name = name; this.owesMe = owesMe; this.willPay = willPay;
  }
  public String  getName()    { return name;    }
  public String  getOwesMe()  { return owesMe;  }
  public boolean getWillPay() { return willPay; }
}
```

*cell-shader.css*

```
/** file: cell-shader.css
place in same directory as CellShadedTable.java */

.italic.table-cell { 
  -fx-font-family: "Times New Roman";
  -fx-font-style: italic; 
}
```

**Cell Factory Based Approach**

For reference (and as shown above, not necessary for simple styling operations), information on a custom TableCell based approach to row coloring is in:

- [Updating TableView row appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153838/updating-tableview-row-appearance)
- [Background with 2 colors in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200901/background-with-2-colors-in-javafx)

Comment: Well, first of all, thanks for your reply and complete application example!  Umm, I can't get this to work for some reason - first I tried it in my application, then I thought it might be a Java version so I downloaded and configured 1.8b92.  Finally I copied your code into a new project but it still refuses to show it like your screenshot i.e. all my columns are non-italics.  I checked that it was running on 1.8 platform ( on both XP and Win7 ); also tried it with a space between .italic and .table-cell ( showing my ignorance on css syntax ).

Comment: I tried just .table-cell and all cells show in italic; I tried using setID and #italic in the css and just the header row was in italic.  I seem to have run out of things to check.  Any ideas anyone?  PS I enjoyed your humour in the table contents ;-)

Comment: Floundered yet again on those 4 jar files needed in NetBeans for jre7 (jfxrt.jar, deploy.jar, javaws.jar and plugin.jar)!  These are apparently not needed to be added for jre8.  Removed them and yes, thanks, that works!

Comment: And just one more thing for anyone coming this way - using JDK8b92 this works on Win7 but not XP

Comment: Updated based on further testing for T-and-M Mike's comments