# TableView Cell Span

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Is there any way to make a TableCell span horizontally? I want to create a tableview in JavaFX 2.2 similar to the one showed in the attached image

[image: sample]
<sub>(source: [fxexperience.com](http://cache.fxexperience.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Picture2.png))</sub>

By the way, the image came from a sample of this funcionality but it is specific for Java FX 8.0. I've been trying to use a rowFactory but there isn't enough documentation on how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cell spanning in the JavaFX platform was implemented for Java 8, then cut as part of feature trim.
It may go into a future release.

The feature request to track for cell spanning is [RT-24747 Cell spanning / merging in TableView](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24747)<sup>1</sup>.  Which is just the feature request that provided the image referenced in your question.

The linked feature request includes sample code for showing a table with row and column spanning for cells.  The sample code relies on a patch attached to the feature request.  The patch modifies JavaFX controls code for Java 8.

You can study the code and patch in the feature request to determine if you can implement such technology for yourself in user code without patching the JavaFX runtime.

---

The only code I know which customizes the row factory is the code in openjfx for the default TableView row handling - and that's not straightforward.  For reference, the code is in [TableRow.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/javafx/scene/control/TableRow.java), [TableRowSkinBase.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/018368ab7327/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableRowSkinBase.java) and [TableRowSkin.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableRowSkin.java).

An alternative to implementing your own row factory is  [Updating TableView row appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153838/updating-tableview-row-appearanc), that uses css to modify the style of certain cells or an entire row rather than making use of a completely custom row factory.  Rather than implementing an entirely new row factory, you may be able to get the effect you want by modifying css styles to remove line separators between spanned cells .

Use of the [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) or the [SceneBuilder CSS Analyzer](https://blogs.oracle.com/jeromec/entry/using_the_new_css_analyzer) tools may assist in determining the required css styles to be modified.

---

1. Unfortunately the feature request link RT-24747 is dead, as the JavaFX bug tracker was merged into OpenJDK, and I don't know the equivalent link in the current bug tracker.  As far as I know the feature was never implemented.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, I'll take a look at it. By the way, do you have any good example of how to use the rowfactory?

Comment: @Issac, added the info I know regarding row factories and css styling of tables

Comment: @jewelsea, I followed the links you provided for the row-factory strategy, but I could not find anything applicable to the implementation of a row factory there.  Help?

Comment: There is an [example of using a row factory in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39080984/1155209), though it does not modify the row factory for column spanning support (it modifies it for styling purposes), modifications of the row factory for column spanning support would probably be a difficult task.