# JavaFX: Costum background-color for TableCell via CellFactory?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, tableview, tablecell

Is there a possibility to change the background-color of a TableCell in a TableView dependent on its text/value, while rendering?

For each column I set a CellValueFactory to fill it with my data like this:

```
[...].setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Row, String>("..."));
```

I thought about building a Callback and set it as a CellFactory afterwards, but i dont know how to get the current Cell as a TableCell to modify its backgroundcolor...

Or how to iterate through every Cell after rendering and check the value?

Comment: Also similar to [Updating TableView row appearance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153838/updating-tableview-row-appearance).

Comment: [Sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5470095).